# returning multible objects with a property of >= number

Tags: angularjs

I have managed to filter out what i want, the problem is it only brings back the first object in the database that matches it. i am trying to have a select box with filter by the job salary minimum. $50,000 $60,000 and so on. for example, when i select the $50,000 option the only result returned is jobs that have there salary set at exactly 50000. I need everything returned that is above 50000. any help is appreciated.

Controller

```
 $scope.salaryFilter = function (min) {
        return min.salaryMin >= $scope.salary_Min ;
    }
```

View

```
<label>Salary Desired:</label><br />
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="search.salaryMin">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="salary in jobArray | filter:salaryFilter"></option>
        <option ng-model="salary_salaryMin" value="50000">$50,000</option>
        <option ng-model="salary.salaryMin" value="60000">$60,000</option>
        <option ng-model="salary.salaryMin" value="70000">$70,000</option>
        <option ng-model="salary.salaryMin" value="80000">$80,000</option>
        <option ng-model="salary.salaryMin" value="90000">$90,000</option>
        <option ng-model="salary.salaryMin" value="100000">$100,000</option>
    </select><br />
```

Comment: What are you talking about? What is your question? Is there a prequel to all this?

Comment: It looks like you've added the output of ng-repeat rather than just the code you're using, is that right? We should really know more of what you're doing in order to see where you're going wrong. I can post a plunker of how to do this but it may be better if we can let you know where you've actually gone wrong

Comment: Sorry if I didn't give enough information. I guess I should have asked what is wrong with my filter in my controller. I need it to return all objects in my sql table with a property of 'salaryMin'  greater than the value on each option. The data is being pulled from the database with $scope.JobArray = Job.query() ;

Comment: I am not at my computer right now. If you need more information then I will post more code if need be. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Your filter is fine, and should work provided `jobArray` has the correct format and `$scope.salary_Min` is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rocJpf2rYaLi86vpSipS) with a basic example of how to do this.

From the behaviour you describe, it sounds like you may be matching strings rather than integers, but we won't know if you don't show us more code

Controller:

```
$scope.data = [
{
  "val":27000,
  "text":"$27,000"
},{
  "val":29000,
  "text":"$29,000"
},{
  "val":50000,
  "text":"$50,000"
},{
  "val":70000,
  "text":"$70,000"
}];
$scope.name = "John";
$scope.salaryMin = 27000;
$scope.salaryFilter = function(salary) {
if (salary.val >= $scope.salaryMin)
  return true;
}
```

Template:

```
<select >
    <option ng-repeat="salary in data | filter: salaryFilter" value="{{ salary.val }}">{{ salary.text }}</option>
</select>
```

Changing the value of `$scope.salaryMin`  will filter the data

### Edit

#### The problem is shown in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/STdThDsTqXbQpGpArVEn?p=preview), and i've created [a fork here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l30b122cDWInUToDyIF7?p=preview) which fixes the issue

There were a couple problems

We're setting the individual salary options manually in the option list, so there's no need for the `ng-repeat` in our salary select box. We also need this select box to set the `$scope.salary_Min` variable, so we shouldn't have `ng-model` set to `salary.salaryMin` on the option tags.

```
        <!-- REMOVE THIS -->
        <option ng-repeat="salary in jobArray | filter:salaryFilter"></option>
        <!-- REMOVE ng-model FROM these -->
        <option ng-model="salary_salaryMin" value="50000">$50,000</option>
        <option ng-model="salary.salaryMin" value="60000">$60,000</option>
        <option ng-model="salary.salaryMin" value="70000">$70,000</option>
        <option ng-model="salary.salaryMin" value="80000">$80,000</option>
        <option ng-model="salary.salaryMin" value="90000">$90,000</option>
        <option ng-model="salary.salaryMin" value="100000">$100,000</option>
```

Because we want the select box to set the `$scope.salary_Min` variable (which is used in our filter), we add `ng-model` to the select tag

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="salary_Min">
```

We previously had the `salaryFilter` on our option tag, but we want to use it to filter the table. So we add it to the table where we're using `ng-repeat`. It's okay to keep the existing search filter because filters in Angularjs are stackable

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in jobArray  | filter:search | filter:salaryFilter">
<td>{{job.jobTitle}}</td>
<td>{{job.companyName}}</td>
<td>{{job.description}}</td>
<td>{{job.city}}</td>
<td>{{job.salaryMin}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is nearly done. The one issue left is that these values are being interpreted as strings by our filter, which can cause some confusing results. We just need to make sure they're interpreted as integers using `parseInt()`

```
$scope.salaryFilter = function (min) {
        return parseInt(min.salaryMin) >= parseInt($scope.salary_Min) ;
    };
```

Comment: ok, thank you for your patience, i am new to this and i never thought about using plunker. i set one up with my data.   http://plnkr.co/edit/STdThDsTqXbQpGpArVEn?p=preview

Comment: No problem, thanks for adding the plunker :) - I've made a few edits to get it working, will update my answer to explain where you went off track. http://plnkr.co/edit/l30b122cDWInUToDyIF7?p=preview

Comment: I've added that info to the answer, but there's a lot there. If you have trouble following it, it may be that you just dived in too quickly and didn't get a good grounding in how the controller and templates interact. If you read back through the basic tutorials a bit though then it should become clear. Good luck!